# How to build subset of datset with files showing specifc pattern in file names using for loop index

Tags: r, string, for-loop

I have many files to analyse all with names as model as follows (for ease sake, I would report simplified reprex here):

```
A_(ele)_c.xls
A_(ele)_d.xls
A_(ele)_e.xls


B_(ele)_c.xls
B_(ele)_d.xls
B_(ele)_e.xls
```

What I am trying to is to store them in a macro list so that:

```
list$A would contain

c
d
e
```

and:

```
list$B would contain

c
d
e
```

So I am using the following code

```
nm1 = c(LETTERS[1:2])
nm2 = c(letters[3:5])

list = NULL
for (i in Files){
  for (j in nm1){
    for (k in nm2){
      list[[j]][[k]][[i]] = if(str_detect(i, pattern = j) == TRUE){read_excel(i)} 
    }
  }
}
```

which seems to work sorting elements fine but just for the `j index` contained in nm1. How can I modify the `pattern argument` in `str_detect function` to take in account the `k index` too?

Please in case feel free to suggest alternatives to this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to create many objects, I would suggest importing them as a single list. Then you can convert the list elements into a single dataset (given the structure is homogeneous) and create indicators for A, B, C and a, b, c etc. I also suggest using `fs::dir_ls()` or `dir()` to build the file paths by inspecting what is inside your folder.

A workflow could look like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

# create vector of file paths
paths <- fs::dir_ls()

# this vector could look like this
c(
  "A_(ele)_c.xls",
  "A_(ele)_d.xls",
  "A_(ele)_e.xls",
  "B_(ele)_c.xls",
  "B_(ele)_d.xls",
  "B_(ele)_e.xls"
)

# read in all excel files into a single list
dat <- map(paths, readxl::read_xls)

# row-bind all datasets (if columns match) and create indices for A, B, C as well as c, d, e
dat |> 
  list_rbind(names_to = "filename") |> 
  mutate(
    id1 = str_extract(filename, "^\\w"),
    id2 = str_extract(filename, "_(\\w).xls", group = 1)
  ) |> 
  select(!filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, that would be to me easier if I had some basics on how to create the string for the common pattern (that you have used as an argument of str_extract).  Cannot really understand how they should be created

Comment: Moreover, thsi code on my end returns error `Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection`